# Convert data frame imported from csv file back to the manual data.frame import command

Tags: r

I have some data in a csv file generated by excel which i import in R using the read.csv command in the form of a data frame. Lets say a table like so:

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

where A, B, C are column names.

I would like to keep the data of the csv file in my r script so it is less likely for the link between the data and the r script to be broken if the csv file is moved/lost. Is it possible to work backwards once the csv data are imported and automatically generate the data.frame command necessary to recreate the data frame imported from the csv file? In this example that would be:

```
data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(4,5,6),C=c(7,8,9))
```

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Yes, it is. The command `dput` outputs the objects, dataframes or other, in a select/run-able representation. Try `dput(df)`; rm(df); `df <- the output of dput`.

Comment: There are also the `save` and `load` functions. See their help pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an R instruction that recreates an R object, that instruction is `dput`.

In this example I will create a dataframe `df1` using your code, make a copy of it, `df2`, then remove the original with `rm`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(4,5,6),C=c(7,8,9))
df2 <- df1

dput(df1)
rm(df1)
```

Now assign the output of `dput` to a *new* dataframe named `df1`. The newly created `df1` is identical to the old `df2`.

```
df1 <-
structure(list(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6), C = c(7, 8, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

identical(df1, df2)
#[1] TRUE
```